# How should I point to a record field in case of extensible object types?

Tags: object, ocaml, reason, lenses

Thinking of a way to define a simple lens on an object in Reason.

I try to use extensible objects (with `..` prepended to field list) with the following code:

```
type hasName('a, 't) = {.. name: 't} as 'a;
type lens('s, 'v) = {
  get: 's => 'v,
  set: ('s, 'v) => 's,
};
let nameLens: lens(hasName('a, 't), 't) = {
  get: s => s.name,
  set: (s, v) => {...s, name: v},
}
```

I get "The record field name can't be found." error, though the type of `hasName` should definitely have one... What am I doing wrong here?

Disclaimer: I am really new to Reason/OCaml, so I may miss some obvious things.

Answer (score 5):

The error message isn't great (to put it mildly), but if you read carefully it does point to the problem. It says "The **record field** name can't be found.", which isn't so odd considering what you have is an object, not a record. This is an error because object members are accessed with `#`, not `.` (see [the Reason docs on objects](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/object)).

As I understand it, the reason for this is that OCaml doesn't support ad hoc polymorphism (ie. function or operator overloading) and so in order for the type inference to work well it therefore needs to distinguish operations on different types syntactically. I also suspect the reason it doesn't just say "dude, this is an object, not a record" is that the type system has no concept of any-record-type, but requires a specific record type. So it tries to first find the field in order to then identify the specific record type associated with it. If it can't find the field it isn't considered a type error because there is no proper type to conflict with.

In any case, the getter is solved easily enough by using `#` instead of `.`. The setter is more problematic, however. Here too you're using record update syntax and will get a similar error, but unfortunately there is no direct equivalent for objects.

One part of what makes objects object-oriented is that their implementation is hidden. You can't copy an object from the outside if you don't know what's inside. And while you can create a different object conforming to the same object type, you can only do so if you know the concrete type. Which in this case you don't.

So the way to update an object immutably is to do it from inside the object, in a setter method, where you know everything you need to know. The syntax for immutably updating the current object is `{<name: newName>}`, which is only valid within a method definition. And then of course we also need to add this setter method to the `hasName` type.

Putting this all together we end up with this:

```rust
type hasName('a, 't) =
  {
    ..
    name: 't,
    setName: 't => 'a,
  } as 'a;

type lens('s, 'v) = {
  get: 's => 'v,
  set: ('s, 'v) => 's,
};

let nameLens: lens(hasName('a, 't), 't) = {
  get: s => s#name,
  set: (s, v) => s#setName(v),
};

let obj = {
  val name =
    "myName";

  pub name =
    name;

  pub setName = newName =>
    {<name: newName>}
};

nameLens.set(obj, "newName")
  |> nameLens.get
  |> print_endline
```

Comment: yup you're completely right about the reason OCaml uses different operators for different types.

Comment: A small point: when the "record field not found" error is raised, the record projection ` r . name` is not yet typed. The typechecker was trying to find all record labels named `field` before trying to type `field`. Since it could not find any label, it raised an error, but the error is still a typechecker error.

Comment: @octachron Thanks for the clarification. I suppose it would be more accurate to say that it's not a unification error perhaps?

Comment: Indeed, it is not an unification error, because the typechecker failed to find types to unify. And like you said, the typechecker has no notion of a record kind (or any kinds) and thus it cannot unify the kind of `s` with the record kind before checking the label.